# PhoneGap Sample with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to find a sample app of a JQuery Mobile app that is hosted via PhoneGap. Specifically, I'm looking for a sample that queries Twitter. I assumed there would be 500 of these out on the internet. Unfortunately, I can't find a single one.

The reason I'm looking for one is because I'm having problems interacting with a cross-domain web service. This seemed like it would be the simplest example. Can someone please help me out?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](https://github.com/rsepulveda2/Twitter-Mobile)?

When you are running the app as part of PhoneGap you will no longer have any x-domain issues. The restriction does not apply to mobile applications.

From [the PhoneGap FAQ](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ):

> The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply.
>   (in Android,you may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: I hate to be a nuisance. However, do you know of something that will just display a query or timeline. I don't want to use oauth etc. Thanks.